# AccessDenied when PUT to AWS S3 presignedUrl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im trying to upload file to my bucket using presigned url. Bucket is publicly accessible for all kind of operation and my IAM user is allowed to do everything.

I generate presigned url using aws sdk and everything works, it genetates presigned url for me.

```
      const s3Client = new AWS.S3({
        ...settings,
        signatureVersion: "v4", // I tried with and without this. 
      });
      const params = {
        Bucket: "bucketname",
        Key: file.id,
        Expires: 600,
        ContentType: file.type,
        ACL: "public-read",
      };
      const signedUrl = s3Client.getSignedUrl("putObject", params);
```

However when im trying to use this url on client it gives me :

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>0FGJ2SEXHH7V9J5A</RequestId>
  <HostId>d3fhlknPq2Zylo+w56mU2a5YTZ/lNdV/c00VxVm4LJc61Uz/OtU1cRdM/FY0M9uDnmwFx1KHRUk=</HostId> 
</Error>"
```

Nothing in message, just access denied. Any idea of what could be reason?

Comment: What do you mean by "publicly accessible"? Does it allow for anonymous uploads?

Comment: Have you check the CORS Permissions? Maybe your bucket is not allowed to access from the origin that was created with SDK. I'm not sure it's exactly related with CORS but seems a permission tab issue anyway.